# Can someone explain to me about the right steps to get this answer for this java code, BigO/running time?

Tags: java, big-o

```
sum = 0;
 for(i=0;i<sqrt(n)/2;i++)
sum++;
 for(j=0;j<sqrt(n)/4;j++)
sum++;
for(k=0; k<8+j; k++)
 sum++;
```

The question is asking if it takes 10ms to run program for n = 100, how large a problem can be solved in 40 ms. The answer is 1600. My question is how did they get to 1600, I tried to plug it in N but I keep getting 200 instead?. Do I plug for the first N loop or the second N loop?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the number of times the loops run. The first goes for `sqrt(n) / 2` iterations, the second `sqrt(n) / 4` and the last for `8 + j` where j is some value (constant in the loop). Thus, for this entire code we have a complexity of `sqrt(n) / 2 + sqrt(n) / 4 + 8 + j`. In order to get the Big O notation, we take the *fastest increasing* one of these, ignoring constants i.e. `sqrt(n)`. This gives us that the code runs in `sqrt(n)` time for a large n. Now we simply have to find an n such that `sqrt(n) = 40` which is simply 40^2 = 1600.

Note also that this question is a bit silly, considering that Big O notation deals with only comparisons with large values of n (as we disregard constants and most terms). As such to do any form of computation like this with them is very odd indeed.

Comment: Thank you very much!so I'm confused about one part, once I take all the constant out, do I go for the first sqrt(n) because it is the fastest?

Comment: Both are `sqrt(n)` once the constant is removed. Beyond that it doesn't matter which you 'choose'. If this answers the question, please accept the answer to remove it from the "Unanswered Questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop with i is about the same runtime as the for loop with j and k.
This is because j loops from 0 to sqrt(n)/4 where as k loops from 0 to 8+j which is close enough to looping from 0 to j. So the loops j and k iterate sqrt(n)/4 * 2 times which is just sqrt(n)/2 which is the same amount of iterations as the loop containing i.

Essentially you can boil it down to

```
for (i=0; i < sqrt(n); i++)
```

after doing this simplification and then you can just plug in for n.

Comment: sorry to bother you but I'm really confused. can you please give me the list of steps on how to solve this problem, like from the 1st step?

Answer (score 0):

All the runtime related to `n` deals with the square root of `n`.

We know that the run time scales proportionately to the square root of n, so we can say that the ratio of the square root of 100 to the runtime of 10ms will be equal to the ratio of the square root of x to the run time of 40ms, where x is the value of n which can be completed in 40 ms

Symbolically, that looks like this:

sqrt(100) / 10 = sqrt(x) / 40

A little algebra, and you get the value of `n` which will run in 40 seconds:

10 / 10 = sqrt(x) / 40

1 = sqrt(x) / 40

sqrt(x) = 40

x = 40^2

Comment: sorry to bother you but I'm so confused. can you give me the list of steps on how to solve this problem! Please help me!

Comment: Thank you! my last question what happend to the /2, since you plugged 100 into the loop, but shouldn't you use sqrt of 100 divide by 2?

Comment: We only care about the change in the overall run time with respect to n.  When doing runtime analysis, you discard any coefficients.